# Show selected values and also other values in multi-select list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, multi-select

I'm trying to display selected values in multi-select when I try to edit the page
**I want to show the list of all data but data should no-repeat show selected and then all other data**
I have two arrays in view one is selected values and the other arrays have all values so how can I apply a condition in foreach loop that not repeat the values

My laravel blade code is:

```
@if( Auth::user()->role == "admin" || Auth::user()->role == "managers" )
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Välj hanterare<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="handler_id[]" multiple data-live-search="true"
                        id="sel1">
                        @foreach($selected_handlers_names as $item)
                        <option value="{{$item->id}}" selected="selected">{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        @foreach($handlers as $items)
                        <option value="{{$items->id}}">{{$items->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('handler'))
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('handler') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                @endif
```

Comment: Are `$handlers` and `$selected_handlers_names` eloquent collections?

Comment: And what's your question about this code?

Comment: @NicoHaase i want to render both array data but after condition like data should not repeat I also edit the question

Comment: @DimitriMostrey No, also I edit the question now